# Why does custom domain connected to Firebase from Bluehost not work?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, bluehost

I added custom domain (online.littlegenius.net) to Firebase hosting from Bluehost. I added all TXT records & A records given by Firebase. And Firebase successfully verify it. It's been three days since it is verified but the custom domain status on Firebase hosting is still showing `Needs Setup`. Just to verify which side is having issue, I added another custom domain ( kmh.nextechmm.com ), this one works pretty fine within 24 hours. How can I solve the issue for online.littlegenius.net ?

Comment: If you've done the same setup for both, it's unlikely to be in the configuration. In that case your best bet is to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did. Waiting for their reply. But I guess this cannot be Firebase issue, can be Bluehost. I already had a talk with Bluehost support as well. Unfortunately, no fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set TXT and A records like this

| Type | Host | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *DNS TXT record inputs* |  |  |
| TXT | @ | verification value provided in Firebase console |
| *DNS A records inputs* |  |  |
| A | @ | 199.36.158.100 |

Firebase has some [examples here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain). Bluehost is not included but is the same idea